# Whether SOA can be Java Bean?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soa, javabeans

My final year project topic is Web-services using SOA. In this we were planning to build individual components like Login, Profile Page, Captcha, etc.. We will then build a demo web application using those components.

I have two questions :

1. Do these components(Login, Profile Page, Captcha) qualify as services?
2. Can these components be built using Java Beans?

Comment: please give answers......please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. They can be services, although almost anything request-able could be considered a service.  You could implement it RESTfully and you could send the form in any format such as form-data(easiest), xml, or json.
2. Yes, especially from the standpoint of the data model.  The data sent in can be populated into a java bean which is then processed.

Answer (score 0):

With an SOA you tend to write services such as Login etc and then write applications that leverage the services. Profile Page doesn't sound like a service to me. You could have a User Profile service and then a web application could use this service to build a profile page.

Comment: @qwerky : Can it be built using Beans?